# Не получается создать Angular TreeView

Tags: java, веб-программирование, angular

Никак не получается создать Tree c Динамической загрузкой детей для обьекта Observable .
Объект Node имеет поля :

```
id?: number;
parentId?: number;
title?: string;
children?: Array<Node>;
```

Все примеры в официальной документации приводятся с уже готовым Json по типу :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но никто не делает это с объектами.
Может кто сталкивался ?

Comment: Первая же [ссылка в гугле](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) ведет к примеру `Tree with dynamic data`

Comment: Вопрос в том КАК подвязать Observable в такой вид что бы сделать Tree.

Comment: ок, [вторая ссылка в гугле](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/lazy-loaded-treeview-in-angular-2.0) `In this article I will show how to create a lazy loaded treeview using RxJs Observables`